# cordova-plugin-camera installed but xcode saying plugin is not installed

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, camera, cordova-plugins

I am trying to get `cordova-plugin-camera` working on my Ionic app. I installed it using `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera --save` and then `npm i --save @ionic-native/camera`. The node_modules folder for the package is populated and the plugin exists in all my plugins folders, I have also verified that `cordova plugin list` shows the plugin. I'm using the following code to attempt to start the camera but it is not working:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Platform } from "ionic-angular";
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from "@ionic-native/camera";

@Component({
  selector: "page-camera",
  templateUrl: "camera.html"
})
export class CameraPage {
  public base64Image: string;

  constructor(public camera: Camera, public platform: Platform) {}

  takePicture() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.camera
        .getPicture({
          destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
          targetWidth: 1000,
          targetHeight: 1000
        })
        .then(
          imageData => {
            // imageData is a base64 encoded string
            this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
          },
          err => {
            console.log(err);
          }
        );
    });
  }
}
```

When running this and clicking the button that calls `takePicture()` I get no camera launched and no console errors but inside of safari I get the following error:

```
2018-12-13 11:31:24.183490-0500 MyApp[3844:312133] ERROR: Plugin 'Camera' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2018-12-13 11:31:24.183546-0500 MyApp[3844:312133] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 142] FAILED pluginJSON = ["Camera1764610053","Camera","takePicture",[50,0,1,1000,1000,0,0,false,false,false,null,0]]
```

Comment: How and where are you running this? Is this platform supported by the camera plugin?

Comment: @janpio I have a separate page for the camera. My iPhone platform is definitely supported.

Comment: You didn't explicitly mention in your description that you are running on iOS. Cordova plugins are only available after `deviceready`, maybe https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#ready will fix your issue.

Comment: @janpio That does not solve my issue. I should be able to launch it via a function.

Comment: @janpio I have updated my code to what i'm using with `platform.ready()`. It is still throwing the exact same error.

Comment: Tried `cordova platform rm ios` and then `cordova platform add ios` already?

Comment: @janpio Not an option with the way my app is setup. We modify our platform pretty heavily.

Comment: Removing and then re-adding the plugin?

Comment: Do you have the NSCameraUsageDescription(Apple Requirement) in your config.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reset my branch and reinstalled, did the trick. I'm unsure of what was happening but think it was just installing improperly.